# When someone's heartbeat is too fast. E.g. more than 100 beats per minute "BPM"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, idiomatic-language

What shall I say to indicate that my hear it beating too faster than it's normal condition out of emotions, anxiety, anger, stress, fear and some other emotional factors?

What I think should work is as the self-made sentence below which hits lots of google results if you search it:

> - My heart is beating too fast / hard.

But I doubt if it is the way I have to say it in common English or there is a fixed-term which can be understood by all English-speaking people.

Meanwhile in my language when because of exercise someone's heart it beating faster than it's normal beat rate, there is a similar but absolutely different construction to indicate this message. What about English language?

Comment: BPM is a measure of *heart rate* (or *heartrate*); in technical contexts we'd speak of an "*elevated* heartrate".

Comment: @StoneyB so what shall I say here in normal English? Imagine I have referred to a doctor and I am going to tell them about my heart rate situation which is beating too hard / fast. What is the normal sentence which is usually used here?

Comment: One of the problems I have with your questions is that you ask for **the normal** sentence for expressing a very general notion. In most cases there are several ways of expressing these thoughts, any of which might be perfectly acceptable across a fairly wide range of situations.

Comment: @StoneyB as you are one of the oldest moderators on this forum, you are well-aware about the type of my questions. Actually, based on what I explain and the examples I provide, I am looking for the closest sentence in English. But if sometimes based on lingual gaps, a native speaker would  need a more comprehensive context, please let me know. What I explain, based on my own language is quite enough to be understood the meaning in my questions. :) Thank you again.

Comment: "My heart rate's up", "My heart's racing" if you're speaking of a more or less continuous phenomenon. "My heart's beating" or "My heart beats uncomfortably fast when ...".  "My heart rate shoots up when ...", "My heart races when ..." "My heart pounds like a jackhammer when ..." "What makes my seated heart knock at my ribs, Against the use of nature?" (That last isn't serious, but a quote from Shakespeare!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of idioms:

> My heart is *racing*
>
> My heart is beating *out of control*.

Also:

> My heart wants to *jump out of my chest*.  (more related to anxiety or strong emotion than simple heart rate)

The medical term for this is **tachycardia** but I'm not sure how many native speakers would know this (unless they are fans of TV medical dramas).

Of course you could just say "my heart is beating really fast".  If you are exercising, however, it's more common to talk about your *breath* than your heart rate (even though both go together).

> Let me *catch my breath*.
>
> I'm *out of breath*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive respond. But I was wondering if these two sentences mean the same: **"My heart is racing"** and **"my heart is beating really fast"** @Andrew

Comment: Yes, they are the same.  "Racing" is idiomatic for "going really fast" and can apply to other things than heartbeat, e.g. "They are racing to get their work done and meet the deadline."